# How can I change the data stored internally in my text file using Python?

Tags: python, csv

My program has to assign a case number to each user who runs the program. I want to store the number 1 in the text file and assign it as the case number for the first person who opens the text file. Once the program has finished running I want to increase the number in the text file by 1 so that the next person who uses the program has a different case number.

EDIT:

This is pretty straightforward, open the file, read it, add one to the number read. Assign that as your new case number. Then write to the file, and close it.

Comment: Read basic file IO using python.That should get you started and then post your code here if you cannot finish what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Open the file and save the content. Then find the line and edit it. Then write all the lines back into the file with argument **'w'**. Nothing complicated.

Comment: What inquisitive said.  Please try and create a program yourself and if you encounter issues come back and post your code and the errors you are running into.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Stack Overflow is neither a forum nor a tutorial, code-writing, or homework service. This is a Q&A site where *specific* programming questions (usually, but not always, including some code) get *specific* answers. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also follow the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: Sorry about this next time I will try to ask better questions and research beforehand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the python manuals for further details about file writing and reading. This is a basic method to write a number to a file:

```
with open("myfile.txt", "a") as file:
    file.write("0")
```